# php timing out on Mac OS

Tags: php, macos, server

I am working on a very complex webapp that uses a function with a lot of process, the function seems working on both windows and linux based OS, but when I tried it on a Mac computer(10.10 Yosemite) it is timing out. I already tried increasing `max_execution_time` to 300 but it didn't work.

As I investigate, I monitored the process on the server while using a Mac and found out that the `php-cgi` has 100% cpu usage, but when I use other OS like Ubuntu, Win10, Win7 it is working fine.

I am also using the same browser (Google Chrome) on each OS

Is there a difference between mac os and other OS? or is it sending other requests to the server that made the cpu usage 100%.

here's the function that causing this timeout. and I am using codeigniter

```
$uid = $amember_user['user_id'];



    if(isset($_POST["ptnt"])){
        $savestype = "patent";
        $result = $_SESSION["modified_ids"];    
    } else {
        $result = $_SESSION["t_modified_ids"];  
        $savestype = "trademark";
    }

    $type = $this->input->post("type"); 
    switch ($this->input->post("save_type")) {
        case 2:
            $savetype = 0;
        break;
        case 3:
            $savetype = 0;
        break;
        default:
            $savetype = $this->input->post("save_type");
            break;
    }

    $resname = $this->input->post("resname");
    $details = array("type"=>$this->input->post("search_type"),
                    "name"=>htmlspecialchars($this->input->post("resname")),
                    "save_type"=>$savetype,
                    "published"=>$this->input->post("published_res"),
                    "query"=>$this->db->escape_str($this->input->post("resquery")),
                    "user_id"=>$uid,
                    "share_opt"=>$this->input->post("shareopt"),
                    "share_email"=>htmlspecialchars($this->input->post("shareemail")),
                    "sched_type"=>$this->input->post("schedtype"),
                    "notes"=>htmlspecialchars($this->input->post("saved_note")),
                    "records"=>count($result),
                    "security"=>$this->input->post("security"),
                    "security_code"=>$this->input->post("securitycode"),
                    "link"=>$this->input->post("url"),
                    "date"=>strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%m",strtotime("now"))
                    );
                    $amnamef = $amember_user['name_f'];
                    $amnamel = $amember_user['name_l'];
    $content = "<h3>Hello,</h3><p><strong>{$amnamef} {$amnamel}</strong> shared a PTODirect Search Link with you for the search titled <strong>{$resname}</strong></p>";
    $content .= "<strong>".$this->input->post("saved_note")."</strong>";
    $content .= "<p>Click on the link below or paste it into a browser to view the Search Result.</p>";

    $email = $this->input->post("shareemail");
    if(isset($_POST['uid'])){
        $details['orig_id'] = $this->input->post("uid");
    }
    $this->db->insert("save_result",$details);
    $id = $this->db->insert_id();
    $content .="<p><a href='".$this->input->post("url")."'>".$this->input->post("url")."</a></p><br/>";

    $urlpath = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/saved/unsubscribe/". base64_encode($this->input->post("shareemail"));

    $mailpost = base64_encode($this->input->post("shareemail"));


    $scode = $this->input->post("securitycode");
    if($id){
        if($this->input->post("shareopt") != "do not share"){
            if($this->input->post("security")=="share with link and password"){
                $content .= "<p>PASSWORD: <strong>{$scode}</strong></p>"; 
            }
            if($this->input->post("shareemail")!=""){
                if($emailunsubscribe != 1) // do not sent email if emailunsubscribe == 1 
                {

                    $share_email = $this->input->post("shareemail");
                    $email = explode(",",$share_email);
                    $content .="Create a free account on PTODirect to save this Search Result and perform your own United States Patent, Trademark and Copyright searches.  Just click on the link above after you've created the free account to see the save options.<br>";



                    foreach($email as $e){
                        $content .= "<br /><br /><img src='http://ptodirect.com/info/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/logo.png'><br />";
                        $content .= "<a href='ptodirect.com'>www.ptodirect.com</a>";
                        $content .= "<p style='color:#333;font-size:10px;'>You are receiving this message because someone Shared the search result with you'>EMAIL PREFERENCES</a> link.</p>";
                        $mail = $this->mailer($content,$e,"Someone shared a PTODirect search result with you!");
                        if($mail){
                            $this->db->insert("save_result_email",array("saveres_id"=>$id,"email"=>$e,"status"=>1));
                        }else{
                            $this->db->insert("save_result_email",array("saveres_id"=>$id,"email"=>$e,"status"=>0));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $qr = array();
        if($this->input->post("save_type")==0){
            if(isset($_POST["ptnt"])){
                foreach($result as $r){
                    $this->db->query("INSERT save_result_detail SET result_id=$r, save_result_id=$id, status_change=''");
                }
            } else {
                foreach($result as $r){
                    $this->load->model("ScheduleSearch_model","ssm");
                    $get_it = $this->ssm->get_insert_ids($r);
                    $stat_d = $get_it[0]->status_date;
                    $this->db->query("INSERT save_result_detail (result_id, save_result_id, status_change) VALUES ($r, $id, $stat_d)");
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
                if(isset($_POST["ptnt"])){
                foreach($result as $r){
                    $this->db->query("INSERT save_result_detail SET result_id=$r, save_result_id=$id, status_change=''");
                }
            } else {
                foreach($result as $r){
                    $this->db->query("INSERT save_result_detail SET result_id=$r, save_result_id=$id, status_change=''");
                }
            }

        }



        if($_POST["dosched"]==1){
            switch($_POST['schedfrequency']){
                case "Once":
                    $nexttrigger = strftime("%Y-%m-%d",strtotime($this->input->post("schedstartdate")));
                break;
                case "Daily":
                    $nexttrigger = strftime("%Y-%m-%d",strtotime("+1 day",strtotime($this->input->post("schedstartdate"))));
                break;
                case "Weekly":
                    $nexttrigger = strftime("%Y-%m-%d",strtotime("+7 days",strtotime($this->input->post("schedstartdate"))));
                break;
                case "Monthly":
                    $nexttrigger = strftime("%Y-%m-%d",strtotime("+1 month",strtotime($this->input->post("schedstartdate"))));
                break;
                case "Yearly":
                    $nexttrigger = strftime("%Y-%m-%d",strtotime("+1 year",strtotime($this->input->post("schedstartdate"))));
                break;
            }
            $arr = array(
                        "name"=>htmlspecialchars($this->input->post("resname")),
                        "email"=>$amember_user['email'],
                        "frequency"=>$this->input->post("schedfrequency"),
                        "schedule"=>strftime("%Y-%m-%d",strtotime($this->input->post("schedstartdate"))),
                        "query"=>$this->db->escape_str($this->input->post("resquery")),
                        "last_triggered_schedule"=>"",
                        "next_trigger_sched"=>$nexttrigger,
                        "sched_type"=>$this->input->post("schedtype"),
                        "type"=>$savestype,
                        "saved_id"=>$id,
                        "user_id"=>$uid,
                        "status"=>1
                        );
            $this->db->insert("search_schedules",$arr);
            $sid = $this->db->insert_id();
            echo "<span style='color:blue; font-weight:bold;'>Schedule and Save result successful.</span>";
        }else{
            echo "<span style='color:blue; font-weight:bold;'>Search result successfully saved.</span>";        
        }
    }
    unset($_SESSION["t_modified_ids"]);
    $_SESSION['managedid'] = 0;
```

t_modified_ids only has 5 array values `array(12345,54321,12322,11112,44421)`

Comment: And what is your question? Why don't you try to simplify your app? Who wants to stare into a blank browser screen for five minutes waiting for that app to return anything

Comment: sorry, my question is, Is there a difference between mac os and other OS? or is it sending other requests to the server that made the cpu usage 100%. I will edit my post now

Comment: Still, what's the point in having an app that takes minutes to load?

Comment: it is not taking 5 minutes when using other computer with different OS

Comment: @NicoHaase that's not a feature, it's a bug and OP is asking for help to fix it.
OP If it only happens in Mac, then it's probably a PHP bug, consider reporting it to https://bugs.php.net/

Comment: What have you tried to spot the problem? There are tools like XHProf or Blackfire to professionally monitor such performance issues, and even adding `var_dump` to find the bottleneck would help

Comment: I tried to monitor it on devetools network tab, check process happening on the server, do `var_dump`. but there is no problem when I use Win10 or other OS aside from Mac. on mac it is timing out and having cpu loaded. I will try XHprof and Blackfire. thanks

Comment: Well, if the problem only occurs on that Mac, you should run all debugging there. The network tab won't help, as it only monitors what happens when the server finishes its execution

Answer (score 0):

try changing the apache config:

set :

```
Timeout 3600
```

it will work;

Comment: Not if the process encounters an infinite loop (which would explain the 5minute timeOut **and** the 100% CPU usage

Comment: Changing timeouts is a really bad idea. Better restructure the app such that it does not hit the timeout

Comment: the function that causes this has no infinite looping at all. I will edit my post and put the code